# StringBuilder initialization in Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, stringbuilder

I needed to use [this method](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/4_2_1/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/common/util/StrUtils.html#join%28java.util.List,%20char%29), and after looking at the source code, I noticed a `StringBuilder` initialization which is not familar to me (I always use the no-argument constructor from `StringBuilder`, i.e. `new StringBuilder()`).

In the method:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(items.size() << 3);
```

From the JavaDoc:

> java.lang.StringBuilder.StringBuilder(int capacity)
>
> Constructs a string builder with no characters in it and an initial
>   capacity specified by the   capacity argument.

Why a bit shift is needed here?

Source code:

```
/** Creates a backslash escaped string, joining all the items. */
  public static String join(List<?> items, char separator) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(items.size() << 3);
    boolean first=true;
    for (Object o : items) {
      String item = o.toString();
      if (first) {
        first = false;
      } else {
        sb.append(separator);
      }
      for (int i=0; i<item.length(); i++) {
        char ch = item.charAt(i);
        if (ch=='\\' || ch == separator) {
          sb.append('\\');
        }
        sb.append(ch);
      }
    }
    return sb.toString();
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Bitshift by 3 means multiplying by 2^3 which is 8. The author must have assumed that each item will take at most 8 characters in the resulting string. Therefore she or he initialized the `StringBuilder` with that capacity so it run efficiently. If the assumption is correct `StringBuilder` will not reallocate internal structures.

Answer (score 3):

X << 3 means multiply X by 8. In your situation it means to allocate space for 8*list.size() characters. In general you should not care about the implementation details of a class that you are using

Comment: "you should not care about the implementation details of a class that you are using" Really? is this a joke?

Comment: SOLID; encapsulation. If you write your code on specific knowledge about the internal workings of a class X, there is high probability  of your code not working properly after the X class has been modified.

Comment: looking at implementation details of well known library can also help you to improve your coding skills

Comment: ok, but that doesn't mean that the implementation details won't change. For example look at the String class in JRE 7 http://www.transylvania-jug.org/archives/5530

Comment: Writing your code such that it will work regardless of the implementation (which is a good thing) is not the same as not caring about the implementation. You *should* care, and avoid using code that works but interacts with the current/common implementation in a bad way.

Answer (score 0):

Is a modality to multiply by 8 `items.size()`.
I think coder just speculate to initialCapacity to prevent (or reduce to minimum) `StringBuilder()` internal buffer reallocation.